# How do I get an external GPU with a hybrid laptop to output a display on Kubuntu?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, gpu, external-monitor, hybrid-graphics

> I link the Arch Wiki a few times. I am using Kubuntu 21.10. It has directions, but *I am not using Arch*.

So... I have a strange configuration. I have a laptop with an Intel CPU, with Intel 360 graphics. I also have an NVIDIA GTX 10XX mobile GPU built into the laptop. I installed the drivers, and it works. I have an external NVIDIA GPU (connected via Thunderbolt). I followed [these directions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/External_GPU) to get it working with Blender. I had to add

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="thunderbolt", ATTR{authorized}=="0", ATTR{authorized}="1"
```

to the `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-removable.rules` file as per [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Thunderbolt#User_device_authorization). I rebooted, and the external GPU showed up in Blender, and worked. Yay. I tried to connect a display via DisplayPort to the external GPU, but it didn't work (the monitor wasn't detecting display output). So, how do I get the external GPU to output to a display?